# Having Trouble with mysql GROUP BY

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table like this

```
id    version_id    field1    field2
1     1             texta      text1
2     2             textb      text2
3     1             textc      text3
4     2             textd      text4
5     3             texte      text5
```

I want to get output like this

```
id    version_id    field1    field2
1     1             texta      text1
3     1             textc      text3
2     2             textb      text2
4     2             textd      text4
5     3             texte      text5
```

but When I use `GROUP BY version_id`

I get This output

```
id    version_id    field1    field2
1     1             texta      text1
2     2             textb      text2
5     3             texte      text5
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT * FROM t ORDER BY group_id
```

-because your issue is about *sorting*, not *grouping*

References:

- [ORDER BY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_by) in SQL
- [GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-extensions.html) in MySQL

Answer (score 1):

```
Select * from table_name ORDER BY version_id
```